# How to retrieve data from firestore in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I want to make an educational app but I don't how to retrieve data in android Studio
I am trying to get and display my user's information when they are logged in. (i.e: name, email)

Here is My Code

```
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

     
        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        //Name Animation
        linearname.setAnimation(rightanim);

        //Email Animation
        linearemail.setAnimation(rightanim);

        //ProfileText Animation
        profile.setAnimation(rightanim);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(networkChangeListener, filter);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(networkChangeListener);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void back(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,Home.class));
    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        fAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successful Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the official documentation on how to fetch data from firebase firestore:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

I edited this section to better fit your needs:

```
db.collection("YOUR COLLECTION NAME" (ie: "Users"))
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getString("YOUR FIELD" (ie: "username" / "email")));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```